# Разница между словами "бунтарь", "мятежник" и "бунтовщик"

Tags: выбор-слова

Викисловарь говорит:

> **бунтарь**: 1. подстрекатель или участник бунта
>   2. *перен.* тот, кто протестует, борется против чего-либо; непокорный человек
>
> **бунтовщик**: подстрекатель или участник бунта
>
> **мятежник**: участник мятежа, бунтовщик

Есть ли разница между этими словами?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Бунт - это стихийное восстание, акция неповиновения. Как правило, при бунте нет явных лидеров и чётких целей. Люди участвующие в бунте - **бунтовщики**.

Мятеж - это **вооружённое** восстание против властей. Чаще всего у мятежа есть лидеры и какая-то программа действий. Люди, участвующие в мятеже - **мятежники**.

**Бунтарь** - это человек, склонный к бунту, но не обязательно в нём участвовавший, участвующий.

Comment: very well put, +1

Answer (score 4):

"Бунтарь" обычно употребляется только в переносном смысле. "Бунтовщик" - только в прямом (участник бунта).

Разница между "мятеж/мятежник" и "бунт/бунтовщик" довольно условная, т.к. эти слова употребляются чаще всего в историческом контексте, и соответственно, мы просто следуем традиции: "медный бунт", "мятеж чехословацкого корпуса" и пр.

Answer (score 2):

They are roughly the same, the differences are very vague if any.

*Мятеж* is more focused on the goal (overthrowing the authority) and as such is used in legalese, *бунт* is more about the process itself. The difference is roughly the same as that between "rebellion" and "riot".

Star Wars' rebels are *мятежники* (or *повстанцы*), "Rebel without a Cause" is *Бунтарь без цели*.

*Бунтарь*, as your dictionary mentions, can be used figuratively:

> Можно быть великим бунтарем для всего мира, как Ибсен, а жить в мещанской обстановке, так что никто из ближайших соседей и не узнает, что жил тут великий бунтарь. // *М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1918)*

, *бунтовщик* would be less appropriate here (though still could be used).

Comment: [Философский словарь Спонвиля](http://philosophy_sponville.academic.ru/264) В современном контексте словом «бунт» все чаще называют индивидуальное поведение (для обозначения коллективного бунта используют слова «беспорядки», «восстание», «революция» и др.). Немалую роль в этом сыграл Камю. «Кто такой бунтарь? – пишет он. – Это человек, который говорит: “нет”.

Answer (score 1):

`Бунтарь` часто употребляется для описания характера человека, как синоним `спонтанный`, `не признающий условностей или правил`, `провокатор`. `Бунтовщики` больше подходит для описания группы действительно бунтующих людей, нежели `бунтари`: второе отражает больше их нрав, нежели конкретную деятельность в некоторый период времени.